# Проблема с организацией рекурсии с возвратом

Tags: javascript

```
let m = 4;
function forward(){

    matrix_g.sort(function(a, b){   
        return a.length - b.length;
        });

    if(matrix_g.length==0){return matrix_new}
    if (matrix_g[0].length>4){

    matrix_help = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_new));
    matrix_g_help = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_g));   
    matrix_new[matrix_g[0][0]][matrix_g[0][2]]=Number(matrix_g[0][i]);
    change = 1;
    solve()
    m=4;
    forward()
    }
    else{back()}



function back(){
    if (matrix_g.length>0){
        if (matrix_g[0].length<5){
            matrix_g =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_g_help));
            matrix_new = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_help));
            i=i+2;
            forward()
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

Необходимо решить судоку.

Функция forward.

1. Сортирую массив из возможных значений пустых ячеек matrix_g по возрастанию. (например, вероятные значения в ячейке '0,0|4,5')
2. Делаю копию массива до изменения, чтобы откатиться в случае ошибки.
3. Беру первое возможное значение и подставляю в массив matrix_new.
4. Далее функция solve() просчитывает возможные значения пустых значений в matrix_new. и формирует из этого массив matrix_g.
5. И так далее. Если первая строка будет содержать пустые значения например  '0,0|', произойдет откат наверх и вместо первого возможного значения подставится второе.

Проблема в том что откатывает сразу наверх, а нужна рекурсия с возвратом, ибо пропускаю почти все ветки значений.

Answer (score 0):

Вы все время запоминаете одни и те же матрицы в:

```
matrix_help = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_new));
matrix_g_help = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_g));
```